# Преобразование BigDecimal в String только с точкой

Tags: java

Я хочу выводить число `BigDecimal` как `String`, причём так, чтобы в выводе число было только с точкой и двумя знаками после точки. Метод `toString` класса `BigDecimal` может выводить число как с точкой, так и в экспоненциальной форме, например:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("13e-2");
System.out.println("Значение: " + bigDecimal.toString());
```

выведет

> Значение: 0.13

а

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("13e-10");
System.out.println("Значение: " + bigDecimal.toString());
```

выведет

> Значение: 1.3E-9

Как сделать так, чтобы значение числа типа `BigDecimal` выводилось в строку только с точкой?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("13e-50");
System.out.println("Значение: " + bigDecimal.toPlainString());
```

Результат:

```
Значение: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013
```

Comment: В вопросе было и про округление до двух знаков после запятой. Стоит добавить, что для этого используется метод `setScale()` и что при сравнении BD чисел сравнивается не только значение, но и порядок после запятой - то есть 2.0 != 2.00

Comment: @pavlofff `setScale()` немножко не для этого используется -- оно меняет значение числа, а не форму его вывода.

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal`. как и другие числовые типы, можно по-всякому форматировать, используя стандартный `Formatter`. Вот цитата из его [описания](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

> Common Java types such as byte, BigDecimal, and Calendar are supported.

Вот пример кода:

```
    System.out.println("Formatting BigDecimal:\n");
    bd = new BigDecimal("1.234567e20");
    bd = bd.divide(new BigDecimal("3"), new MathContext(60)); // To provide enough digits
    System.out.println("toString:       " + bd);
    System.out.println("PlainString:    " + bd.toPlainString());
    System.out.println("Eng. String:    " + bd.toEngineeringString());
    System.out.printf ("Exponential 15: %.15e\n", bd);
    System.out.printf ("Exponential 5:  %.5e\n", bd);
    System.out.printf ("Floating-point: %.5f\n", bd);
    System.out.printf ("General:        %.5g\n", bd);

    System.out.println();
    bd = new BigDecimal("123.4567e-20");
    bd = bd.divide(new BigDecimal("3"), new MathContext(60)); 
    System.out.println("toString:       " + bd);
    System.out.println("PlainString:    " + bd.toPlainString());
    System.out.println("Eng. String:    " + bd.toEngineeringString());
    System.out.printf ("Exponential 15: %.15e\n", bd);
    System.out.printf ("Exponential 5:  %.5e\n", bd);
    System.out.printf ("Floating-point: %.5f\n", bd);
    System.out.printf ("General:        %.5g\n", bd);
```

Этот код выводит

```
    Formatting BigDecimal:
    toString:       41152233333333333333.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333
    PlainString:    41152233333333333333.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333
    Eng. String:    41152233333333333333.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333
    Exponential 15: 4.115223333333333e+19
    Exponential 5:  4.11522e+19
    Floating-point: 41152233333333333333.33333
    General:        4.1152e+19

    toString:       4.11522333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333E-19
    PlainString:    0.000000000000000000411522333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
    Eng. String:    411.522333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333E-21
    Exponential 15: 4.115223333333333e-19
    Exponential 5:  4.11522e-19
    Floating-point: 0.00000
    General:        4.1152e-19
```