# Сокращение результата при десятичных расчетах на java

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

Делаю калькулятор под *Android*. Для расчетов использую *BigDecimal* и в принципе все хорошо, кроме одного момента. Результат, например для *0.0002 + 0.0001* выдается в виде сокращенной записи *3.0Е-4*, в то время как хотелось бы видеть *0.0003*.

**Как сделать, чтобы результат не сокращался?** Особенно это касается небольших чисел, которые и без сокращения легко помещаются в экран.

Comment: А как вы результат выводите?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522835/177345

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, все оказалось даже проще чем я думал )